# how can I convert a GIF to Lottie json?

Tags: json, gif, photoshop, converters, lottie

As you know we can make a lottie animation by "Adobe After Effect" but I want to know how can I do it by "Photoshop"? 
 Is there any way to convert a GIF to Lottie JSON ?

Comment: Seconded I also have this question

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I find a way to solve this problem.
to convert a gif to a Json there are lots of website which convert Gif to Json but none of them has a proper output for lottie library.

so this has two steps to do that :

1. first you must convert Gif file to a video
   I recommended this website:
   [Gif2Mp4](https://ezgif.com/gif-to-mp4)
   or any other converter.
2. in second you must use the link below :

[Video to Lottie Json](https://observablehq.com/@forresto/video-to-lottie)
this is the only website which has a good output to render

and by this Link we are able to convert Photoshop Animation to Json lottie file
first made an animation by Photoshop
then export your Animation in Video format .mp4
and in the end use

[Video to Lottie Json](https://observablehq.com/@forresto/video-to-lottie)

to convert your Video to lottie file

**Be aware: by this way you are gonna lose transparent background according to @Dr.jacky Comment**

Comment: With this solution, you're gonna lose the transparent background.

Comment: Great! simple as that

Comment: Dr.jacky, Your right,
I can't find any way to recover transparency background

Comment: upload a .mov transparent video will create a transparent output

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the same. I am looking for an automated method but a quick search led me here. So I figure it doesn't exist yet. I would assume without having done much research yet we should be able to break the GIF into individual images and then use after effects to create a Lottie version. We will also most likely need to create vector versions of the individual images to save on file size.

Answer (score 3):

This already exists altough its built in ***Python*** you could use some of your own skill to try and convert this into JSON I'll include a link [here](https://pypi.org/project/lottie/).

Comment: python-lottie is a very good library, but please consider providing more than just a link, including a basic example will make more people pay attention to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of converter does not make sense to use at all..

`Gif` has rasterized images in it, and your goal is to have vector (svg) images and to nicely animate paths etc so to be much smaller in sizes of course .. so, no converter of this kind will ever do you good in sense of final result!

Answer (score 2):

There is a new option to convert not only Gift
MP4, MOV, WebM, WebP, GIF, animated PNG and zipped PNG sequence files into Lottie animations

It is still in beta, inside lottiefiles.com in dashboard you will find a button to upload and you can use it

1. Go to lottiefiles.com
2. Sign In
3. Upload your file
4. Download your json file
5. Enjoy

[image]

Answer (score 0):

0. Convert your GIF to TGS. I tried [this](https://github.com/bodqhrohro/giftolottie/) repository but [I wasn't succeed](https://github.com/bodqhrohro/giftolottie/issues/18).

*If you got the error or wasn't succeed on converting GIF to TGS, I'd suggest to start from TGS in first place.*

1. Download the **TGS** format of the sticker with the help of this telegram bot: https://t.me/Stickerdownloadbot or any other ways you know.
2. Convert that **TGS** to Lottie **JSON** with the help of this https://michielp1807.github.io/lottie-editor/#/.
   [Source: https://github.com/MichielP1807/lottie-editor]

<strike>Note: If you upload the generated JSON here: https://edit.lottiefiles.com/ or https://lottiefiles.com/preview, you could see the result and/or edit the file but, sometimes, it's a bit different than what we see via `<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView` in Android. I already issued [this](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/issues/2054).</strike>

**Update:**
1- Go to lottiefiles.com
2- Sign In
3- Upload your file
4- Download your json file

[Source: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/77164680/421467]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77164680/421467)